# DbContext cached data

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I read everywhere that the proper way to get fresh data from the database is to create a new instance of DbContext, and drop the existing. While this may be obvoius for some scenarios, I am finding difficulties to implement this in a more complex scenrario. The type of application in question is client app, where context lives as long as the form/view is displayed.

For example, imagine that we are adding some data of type A (this is the main data), and a specific instance of type A references objects of type B and C (this is the data referenced by ). This means that on the screen I could have loaded list of A, list of B and list of C. Lets say that list of B has received some changes on the network, that I would like to load. How can I refresh the list of B, without the need to fetch all three lists from database (because if I destroy the context, that is what I will need to do?

obvoius mehod would be somethin like

```
Context.Set<B>().AsNoCache().ToList();
```

which we do not have...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the tests I discovered that the only method that refresh data with the current records from the database (added, updated and deleted) is to use ObjectContext's ObjectSet and set MergeOption to OverwriteChanges (DbContext does not expose such a method).

```
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)Context).ObjectContext;
ObjectSet<T> set = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<T>();
set.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;
var list = set.ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

The method you're looking for is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbquery.asnotracking%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

```
Context.Set<B>().AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

Comment: I do not see how AsNoTracking can be used in above scenario, but maybe I do not see something. If I am not tracking something, that means it is not attached to context. If it is not attached to context, then it cannot be updated. In above scenario I am updating data. So, how did you exactly meant this to work?

Comment: @Goran you can attach entities that are not being tracked. You can even attach an entity to a different context to the one that materialised it.

Comment: I know I can attach it. If I atach it, then it is cached. How will I update it, since now it is being tracked, which is the opposite state of what you have suggested?

Comment: I think the trick would be to not have a long lived `Context`. You load your data and close the `Context`. When a change is made you can create a new `Context` instance, attach, save, close.

Comment: The scenario you are talking about is recommended for web apps. For client apss it is recommended to have a context life the same as views/forms life. Imagine if I would need to load 8 different sets (which is my current scenario), on each navigation - not the best performance...

Comment: @Goran the only time it is acceptable to have a single long living context is if you have one user. The context will grow stale over time and there is no way around it.

Comment: I never said there is a single context per app, I am saying there is a single context per view. Since in this case this is a client app (WPF), please read section #lifetime# that talks about context life at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to update an existing list of entities with possibly updated values from the DB, you can use `ObjectContext`'s [Refresh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503718%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
// what to refresh
// this will refresh all cached instances of B entities
var entitiesToRefresh = dbContext.Set<B>().Local;

var objectContext = ( ( IObjectContextAdapter )dbContext ).ObjectContext;
objectContext.Refresh( RefreshMode.StoreWins, entitiesToRefresh );
```

Note this will not load new entities from the DB if there should items added to the list - you would need to requery for those items.

Comment: This is the method which I use when I am working with single entity list. However, I do not see a way I can update data for an object graph? Imagine in a scenario above where A is Invoice, B is InvoiceItem, C is Product, D is Customer, etc. IF Invoice 123 is changed on network, and I am navigating through invoices (back / forward), How will I load the new data for invoice 123, when I navigate to it?

Comment: build a list of entities from the object graph you wish to refresh

Comment: So, lets say I click on the backward button to load previous record. At this point I do not know what a previous record is, so I would need to fetch it from the database (that would get added items). Then I would check if context has it cached. If yes, then I would make three lists, each for parent entity, children and grandchildren, and send those to Refresh. Is this what you are advising, I need to make sure I understood before I do some tests.